# Gnuplot: How to get the coordination (x,y,z) of the point whose z value is the max?

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, max

The data file has 3 columns, corresponding to (x,y,z), and the style is set to be able to draw 3D surface.

I find that the command GPVAL_DATA_Z_MAX can give the max z value, and I want to find the left x,y of the max point, although there maybe more than one point owning the max z.

So, I use GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX, GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX, but I get the wrong position, because the three column are irrelavent, these two commands function like GPVAL_DATA_Z_MAX. **So how can I find the (x,y,z) of the point whose z value is the max?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do another (temporary) plot, which displays only the point where z is max.

I do it like this:

```
plot "Datafile" using ($3==GPVAL_DATA_Z_MAX?$1:NaN):($3==GPVAL_DATA_Z_MAX?$2:NaN):3
```

This will only plot the point(s) where z=GPVAL_DATA_Z_MAX.

After this plot GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX and  GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX will have the values which belong to ().

Comment: Thank you!! I really wish gnuplot could plus such a method, and your solution is so smart!!

Comment: You're welcome! By the way I also use set table "/dev/null" if I do not want the temporary plot to be displayed.
`set table "/dev/null"
plot...
unset table`